# How to add product categories in my own div?

Tags: php, magento

I've created a div called `nav_container` and I'd like the Magento product categories to be placed in that div instead of in the default header.

What is the simplest way to do this? I've researched this for a long time with no solution. Thanks for any advice. I'm using Magento 1.7.

Comment: You might want to give your question a more relevant title. Now it only tells us it's about something Magento related, which is already a tag.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/page/html/topmenu.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme` and simply add in your wrapping div.
2. Edit `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/page/html/header` and find the line: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>` and simply surround it with you div
3. You could also use layout xml, specifically a `page/html_wrapper` block - but for this simple example option 1 or 2 would most likely be the best option

**EDIT**

*Please see below the correct solution after realising your confusion regarding blocks*

Ok, so first of all, blocks have a very specific meaning in Magento, entirely different to that of an html tag.  You can find a definition of blocks here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/magento-design-terminologies4#term-blocks

Now, to move the top nav in 1.7 CE:

As ever with layouts in Magento, you have two main options: Copy over base layout files into your current theme and edit, or use a local.xml file in your theme for all base layout overrides.

There are pros and cons to each - though I would advocate you use local.xml unless there is specific reason not to.  But it is entirely up to you which method you choose :)

**1. Using local.xml**

```
app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml
```

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <!-- Other layout xml -->

    <!-- 
        Unset the nav from the header 
    -->
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>topMenu</alias></action>
    </reference>

    <!-- 
        Insert it into your new containing block
    -->
    <reference name="nav_container">
        <action method="insert"><alias>top.menu</alias></action>
    </reference>

    <!-- Other layout xml -->

</layout>
```

**2. Copying over base files**

First, copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` to `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/page.xml`

Find the header block, which if untouched will be exactly as follows:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
        <label>Navigation Bar</label>
        <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
    </block>
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
        <label>Page Header</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
    </block>
</block>
```

and change to:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
        <label>Page Header</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
    </block>
</block>
```

At this point, you have simply removed the top.menu block from the layout.

Next, you need to add the block back into the layout under the correct node: nav_container.

So, wherever you are currently declaring your nav_container block add as a child node the xml you just removed i.e.:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Finally clear your cache and reload the page.

Comment: The first two don't work: what happens is it simply encases the nav menu in a div with the same id, but still nested inside the header div. Could you please elaborate on option 3?

Comment: So you want to move the navigation out of the header completely and into another, separate block altogether?

Comment: Yes, I made a custom template, what you refer to as 'block' I just refer to as a div. So i'd like it in a div that I've named 'left_container'.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed update! I'd like to use the local.xml method, one confusion... in the second part where I add it back in, which part of that specifies where it is getting added to?

Comment: name="nav_container" specifies the block new containing block and <action method="insert"><alias>top.menu</alias></action> does the inserting